# Как можно оптимизировать алгоритм построения дерева?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация

как мне кажется, все написано оптимально, но.. хотелось бы все-таки ускорить
вот мой код:

```
private async Task DeliveryCallback(
   IMqttClient sender,
   MqttDelivery delivery)
{
   var subTopic = delivery.Topic.Split('/');
   TreeRoot.Add(subTopic);
}
```

`TreeRoot` - это класс, представляющий "дерево", вот как все это выглядит:

```
public readonly SortedDictionary<string, TreeNode> TreeChildren = new();

public void Add(string[] subTopic) =>
   Add(subTopic, Level + 1);

private bool Add(IReadOnlyList<string> topic, int level)
{
   if(level >= topic.Count)
     return false;
   
   var part = topic[level];

   if(!TreeChildren.TryGetValue(part, out var trie))
   {
       TreeChildren.Add(part, trie = new TreeNode(part, level, this));
   }

   trie.Add(topic, level + 1);

   return true;
}
```

Словарь на UI я показывать не могу, поэтому раз в секунду преобразую в плоский список.
Делается это так:
// вызывается 1 раз в 1000 мс

```
private void Update()
{
   AppendItems();
   this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(VisibleChildren));
}

private void AppendItems()
{
   _updateEnqueued = false;

   var flatTreeList = new List<TreeNode>();

   AppendItems(flatTreeList, this);

   VisibleChildren = flatTreeList;
}

static private void AppendItems(
   ICollection<TreeNode> flatTreeList,
   TreeNode treeNode)
{
   flatTreeList.Add(treeNode);

   foreach(var ch in treeNode.TreeChildren)
      AppendItems(flatTreeList, ch.Value);
}
```

Я не уверен, но может стоит `var subTopic = delivery.Topic.Split('/');` заменить на Span и тогда в памяти ненужные строки не будут оставаться?
Что еще можно поправить?

Comment: Так а что именно у вас тормозит? Прежде чем что-то оптимизировать, нужно сначала понять, а стоит ли вообще. И если стоит, то где узкое место.

Comment: Постоянно создаётся `new List<TreeNode>()`. Можно сделать его уровнем выше и в методе `AppendItems` лишь очищать: `flatTreeList.Clear()`

Comment: Вместо `SortedDictionary` скорее всего будет выгоднее взять обычный словарь и сортировать данные непосредственно перед использованием.

Comment: `async Task` без `await` не имеет никакого смысла. Сделайте просто `void`. Либо если сигнатуру метода нельзя изменить, то уберите `async` и добавьте `return Task.CompletedTask;`.

Comment: в данном случае имеет, т.к в этом методе чуть дальше идет `await`. а почему использование специально созданных коллекция для сортировки, хуже чем самостоятельная сортировка? да, я могу сохранять в словарь, а в момент заполнения списка, делать `OrderBy`, но разве это лучше?

Comment: ну еще вот я обратил внимание на следующее: на рабочем пк у меня все быстро выполняется - дерево очень быстро обновляет свое содержимое, а вот на ноутбуке другая картина, там все медленнее. 
наверное проблема в мощности, но странно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68055201/5045688

Comment: [Профлируйте](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) свой код, чтобы выяснить, где узкие места.

Comment: В показанном коде не вижу ни одного `await`.